# How to call a method in another module JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have a class with method performing login

LoginPage.js

```
class loginPage {
  fillCredentials(username, password) {
    cy.get('[id=username]').type(username);
    cy.get('[id=password]').type(password);
    return this;
  }

  clickLogin() {
    cy.contains("Login").click();
  }
}
export default loginPage;
```

I have another spec file for testing:

login.spec.js

```
import {fillCredentials,clickLogin} from '../../support/PageObjects/loginPage'

describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  it('Verification email', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    fillCredentials('username','password')
    clickLogin()
  });
});
```

However, it is giving an error of

```
(0 , _loginPage.fillCredentials) is not a function
```

I know its a wrong way of calling a method. Is there any way I can use the methods without creating an instance of class to access methods

Answer (score 1):

You can do so if you make the methods [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

```js
class loginPage {

  static fillCredentials(username, password) {
    cy.get('[id=username]').type(username);
    cy.get('[id=password]').type(password);
    //return this;  // you can't return "this" because there is no this for static methods
  }

  static clickLogin() {
    cy.contains("Login").click();
  }
}
export default loginPage;
```

```js
import {fillCredentials,clickLogin} from '../../support/PageObjects/loginPage'

describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  it('Verification email', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    fillCredentials('username','password')
    clickLogin()
  });
});
```

---

With static methods you lose `this` which refers to the class instance, and therefore lose the ability to chain methods,

```js
import {fillCredentials,clickLogin} from '../../support/PageObjects/loginPage'

describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  it('Verification email', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    fillCredentials('username','password').clickLogin()  // can't do this with static
  });
});
```

---

As functions instead of a class, this is the pattern

```js
// LoginPage.js

export const fillCredentials = (username, password) => {
  cy.get('[id=username]').type(username);
  cy.get('[id=password]').type(password);
  return this;
}

export const clickLogin = () => {
  cy.contains("Login").click();
}
```

```js
// login.spec (same as you have above)

import { fillCredentials, clickLogin } from '../../support/PageObjects/loginPage'

describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  it('Verification email', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    fillCredentials('username','password')
    clickLogin()
  });
})
```

Be wary of encapsulating test code in page objects, it can lead to over-complicated code.

For example, if you now want to test what happens if password is not entered, you can't use `fillCredentials` because you can't omit the password parameter. So do you add a `fillCredentialsWithoutPassword` function? Do you modify `fillCredentials` to test if `password` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

So, what's going on is that you are mixing up the module structure with is defined by [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with the class-instance pattern.

For this scenario (which is class-instance) the functions are NOT part of the object itself, but of it's [PROTOTYPE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

So in order to get that function you should access it's prototype.

```js
//create a class (class syntax and this one is pretty much the same)
function xx (){}
//this is what class syntax makes to create a method for the class
xx.prototype.theFunctionIwant = function (){}

//create an instance
var example = new xx()

//this is how you can spy that function in the test
xx.prototype.theFunctionIwant
//ƒ (){}
```

Try it out : )

Answer (score 0):

The other answers given will work and solve your exact question, but I fear that making the functions static is an anti-pattern for the Page Object Model. [Check out this article on how to set up a POM for Cypress.](https://www.toolsqa.com/cypress/page-object-pattern-in-cypress/) I would highly encourage you to instantiate the class, similar to below.

```js
//LoginPage.js
export class LoginPage { ... }

//login.spec.js
import { LoginPage } from '../../support/PageObjects/loginPage';

describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  it('Verification email', () => {
    const loginPage = new LoginPage()
    cy.visit('/')
    loginPage.fillCredentials('username','password')
    loginPage.clickLogin()
  });
});
```

You could also use a `beforeEach()` block to instantiate the variable before each test.

```js
describe('User Onboarding Emails', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
  });
  it('Verification email', () => {
    ...
  });
})
```

As an aside, it is usually preferred to name classes beginning with an uppercase (`LoginPage` vs. `loginPage`). When naming a class this way, you can easily differentiate the class vs. the instantiated variable.

Comment: I think Tirath Sojitra already knows all that, since he asks ***[how can] I can use the methods without creating an instance of class to access methods***

Comment: @Seke that's completely fair. I missed that part of the question (oops!). I've updated my answer to reflect that I feel that not instantiating is an anti-pattern for POM.

Comment: Hello @Seke. I was wondering if the POM files like LoginPage.js, HomePage.js, etc are required to be a JS class files only or I can create only functions file?

Comment: Hello @agoff. I was wondering if the POM files like LoginPage.js, HomePage.js, etc are required to be a JS class files only or I can create only functions file?

Comment: You can declare the class _wherever_ you'd like, and then you will need to import it if it is in a separate file. Generally, POM has each Page Object as a separate class in a separate file. If you just made a JS file that only had the functions, that would work, but I don't believe I'd really call that POM.